# Apple Push Notification Service: Certificate Install Server Side?

Tags: php, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I've followed the instructions at [How to build an Apple Push Notification provider server (tutorial)](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/) in an attempt to set up a push notification server.

When I attempt to connect with the following PHP code

```
// connect to apns server
$strAPNSUrl = 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
$strAPNSCert = 'dev.pem';

// generate stream
$oStreamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($oStreamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $strAPNSCert);

// create the socket connection
$oAPNS = stream_socket_client($strAPNSUrl, $iError, $strError, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $oStreamContext);
```

I get the following warning

`Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert`

Based on what information I've been able to find on Google, the issue seems to be my certificate.

I'm generating my csr and pem files in OS X (pem files per the instructions in the tutorial).  Once I have created dev.pem I am uploading it to my hosting provider and attempting to run my php script.  Is this the correct way to create and "install" the certificate?

I've run out of debugging ideas.  Any direction would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Path to `dev.pem` was incorrect on my server.

The instructions are indeed the correct way to generate the .pem file.  Once created it can be used on any machine (not just the machine that generated it).

Comment: Did you find any problem like Absolute and Relative paths?

Comment: I misspelled the file name of my live .pem file.  -.-  Kept overlooking it until I seen this answer which is what made me "carefully" look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to use the same .pem file in your server? And as you said...on any machine.

I have follow this tutorial and I could send messages from my machine (the one were the certificate was generated) but I have tried copy all files and run the script in another machine and I have got the same errors that you have got.

How have you done to make it works in another machine? Have you installed the .pem file? Any special config?

Cheers

Comment: As far as "installing" the .pem file, all I had to do was copy it to a local directory on my server.  The issue was I had moved my php script to a cron directory where I hold my cron jobs, and failed to copy over the .pem file.  Once I moved the .pem file all was well.  My hosting provider is running linux, so the .pem file should be good for any platform.

Comment: File permissions could potentially be an issue.  My .pem is set to 644.

Comment: @Jason George
I changed the file permissions but the error didn't change.

I have done almost the same thing that you've said. I have configured my machine, tested and everything has been working. So, I have tried to copy everything and put in another mac that I have, but in this machine I am getting this error.

Comment: In this doc (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) Apple says that the .p12 must be installed in the new server/machine. Have you done that or only copy/paste run.

Comment: Hey all,

I could figure out the problem.....my mystake was run the script from a different location. it means, I was in the folder A and trying to rum my script like >php -f ../B/apns.php "message with badge" 4. When I've tried to do >php -f apns.php "message with badge" being under folder B it has stared to work.