# PHP not using SSL certificate

Tags: php, nginx, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use a feedback.php file to remove inactive devices from my database.
I have the script working for now code:

```
<?php
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##
##     Copyright (c) 2010 Benjamin Ortuzar Seconde <bortuzar@gmail.com>
##
##     This file is part of APNS.
##
##     APNS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
##     it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
##     published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of
##     the License, or (at your option) any later version.
##
##     APNS is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
##     but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
##     MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
##     GNU General Public License for more details.
##
##     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
##     along with APNS.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
##
##
## $Id: processFeedback.php 168 2010-08-28 01:24:04Z Benjamin Ortuzar Seconde $
##

require_once('config.php');
require_once('classes/DataService.php');
require_once('classes/Apns.php');
echo "<br/>Started processing Feedback";
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set( 'display_errors','1'); 

//get the certificates
$certificates = DataService::singleton()->getCertificates();

foreach ($certificates as $certificate) {

    //only process apps that have a certificate associated to it.
    if($certificate->KeyCertFile == ''){

        echo "<br/>Certfile not set for App: [{$certificate->CertificateName}]";
        continue;
    }
    //var_dump($certificate);
    //connect to feedback server
    $certificatePath = $certificateFolder . '/' . $certificate->KeyCertFile;

    $server = DataService::singleton()->getCertificateServer($certificate->CertificateId, 3);
    $apns = new apns('feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $certificatePath, $certificate->Passphrase);


    //get tokens
    $feedbackTokens = $apns->getFeedbackTokens();

    //close connection
    unset($apns);

    //print the number of tokens to check for
    $countTotal = count($feedbackTokens);
    echo "<br/>There are [{$countTotal}] tokens notified by feedback";

    //loop trough the tokens
    foreach ($feedbackTokens as $feedbackToken) {

        //only DeActivate devices that where updated before they where removed. Otherwise the user could of installed the app again.
        DataService::singleton()->setDeviceInactive($feedbackToken['devtoken'], $app->AppId, $feedbackToken['timestamp']);
    }
}
echo "<br/>Completed processing Feedback";
?>
```

(Full source: https://github.com/bortuzar/PHP-Mysql---Apple-Push-Notification-Server/blob/master)

However I have a problem with connecting to the server. Delivering push notifications work fine but this feedback script doesn't work.
It's not using the certificate that I input this is what happens:

```
<br/>Started processing Feedback<br/>Opening connection to: feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196<br/>Clossing connection to: feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196<br/>There are [0] tokens notified by feedback<br/>Opening connection to: feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196<br/>Clossing connection to: feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196<br/>There are [0] tokens notified by feedback<br/>Completed processing Feedback
```

But, It replies 0 tokens. And when I just connect to a random host it shows the same:

```
<br/>Started processing Feedback<br/>Opening connection to: localhost:80<br/>Clossing connection to: localhost:80<br/>There are [0] tokens notified by feedback<br/>Opening connection to: localhost:80<br/>Clossing connection to: localhost:80<br/>There are [0] tokens notified by feedback<br/>Completed processing Feedback
```

Getting a reply takes a while to.
I guess this has something to do with the certificate if I am not mistaking or am I missing some sort of PHP include?

Comment: @qeremy - he did this at my suggestion. There were multiple unrelated problems with his code - it made more sense not to try to create "one answer solves all" since that would probably not help future SO users finding solutions to their problems. When the comments become the (new) question, it's time for a new question - or such a significant edit to the originally asked question that nobody can follow what happened any more. At least it makes sense to me. If that's the wrong approach I hope a moderator will chip in - or maybe you can provide a link to "good and bad behavior" that I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly from your [earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606970/php-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object/14608370#14608370) your $server variable was NULL. This implies to me that the real problem lies in the line

```
$server = DataService::singleton()->getCertificateServer($certificate->CertificateId, 3);
```

If everything was kosher with your certificate, this should have returned a valid server. But it didn't - which you temporarily worked around by hard coding the `$server` variable in the next line:

```
$apns = new apns('feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $certificatePath, $certificate->Passphrase);
```

In other words - you are right to suspect there is a problem with your certificate.

You might find the information given at this [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635111/apple-push-notification-service-certificate-install-server-side) useful to solve that issue.

Comment: Almost certain that I fixed it now by using the following tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2 and indeed I had to fill in the complete path to the certificate instead of just using /certificates/ck.pem thanks once again!